# Any way to see waveform when using Quick Look on an audio file?

Tags: macos, audio, quicklook, plugins, waveform

Are there any plugins that will allow me to see a waveform when using Quick Look on an audio file?

(I'm using Yosemite.)

Comment: a plug in for quick look? does it has to be quick look?

Comment: Yes, because I want to quickly go through files within Finder. The next best thing so far is http://nulloy.com/ but it's still a separate app I have to launch.

Comment: quick look of the waveform ?

Comment: Yeah like this http://www.simonecoen.com/2012/03/04/idea-for-quick-look-audio-plugin/

Comment: This http://www.audioease.com/Pages/Snapper does it, but a lot more, and is expensive

Comment: Snapper is http://www.audioease.com/Pages/Snapper/snapper.html

Answer (score 1):

Snapper from Audioease has been the best I've found so far.  I have it set to launch at log in so I don't even have to think about it.  It activates the waveform view you're asking for just by clicking once on any audio file.  It also has many other features like format conversion, export, etc.
It's not free but is entirely worth the cost with the time it saves me.

Comment: I tried demo but not working at all on Yosemite